# Create a shared lib that depends on dlib using Cmake

Tags: c++11, dlib

I'm building a shared library in C++ that depends on `dlib` using CMake.

While it has been possible for me to build and install a shared `dlib` using `make` and `make install`, so far I haven't figured out the way to link to this shared `dlib` library.

The examples of usage given in the DLib website always link to a static library.

This is what I have so far:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
project(face_align)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

find_package(dlib)

add_library(face_align SHARED src/mylib.cpp)
target_link_libraries(face_align dlib::dlib)
```

The linker complains like so:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldlib::dlib
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/face_align.dir/build.make:94: recipe for target 'libface_align.so' failed
make[2]: *** [libface_align.so] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/face_align.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/face_align.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

If I remove the `SHARED` from 
`add_library(face_align SHARED src/mylib.cpp)` the project builds successfully. This makes me think that `dlib:dlib` is pointing to the static library. I see that there is a `dlib:dlib_shared` but no success linking to this one either.

Comment: Use add_subdirectory(dlib)

Comment: Hello @DavisKing. Thanks for your comment. Any plans for a find_package feature in the future?

Comment: There is a find_package(). Try the newest dlib

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer seems to be (1) linking to dlib as a static library (2) making the code linking to dlib *position independent*:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
project(face_align)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

# Unfortunately, this only links dlib as static library
add_subdirectory(libs/dlib dlib_build)

add_library(face_align SHARED src/mylib.cpp)
# This makes the target position independent, allowing to link an static library to a dynamic one.
set_target_properties(face_align PROPERTIES POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON) # This made it work

# Link Dlib
target_link_libraries(face_align dlib::dlib)
```

**EDIT:**

Also, in Linux (**I haven't tested this in other S.O.s**) CMake does some magic and, after installing dlib library in shared mode:

```
$ cd $DLIB
$ mkdir build && cd build
$ cmake ../dlib
$ make && make install
```

Is possible to simply add the library using `target_link_libraries` as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
project(face_align)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_library(face_align SHARED src/mylib.cpp)
# Link Dlib
target_link_libraries(face_align dlib)
```

Then, in your code, include headers as follows:

`#include <dlib/your_dlib_header_here.h>`

Comment: For me, it was needed to set dlib::dlib under target_link_libraries